# extract data from column of a file on SD Card and put in array on android phone

Tags: java, android, python

I have one text file in SD Card on Android Phone and in that file there are multiple columns through application.
I want to extract each column data and put into different-2 array.
As I am new to application development, please help me or provide me source code.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: please suggest me how to start ?? I am beginner

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do it's to use something like that :

```
try{
   InputStream flux=new FileInputStream("Your_File"); 
   InputStreamReader lecture=new InputStreamReader(flux);
   BufferedReader buff=new BufferedReader(lecture);
   String ligne;

   while ((ligne=buff.readLine())!=null){
       //Do the action that you want to do for each ligne.
       //If I well understand you need, split each ligne to give each columns.
   }
   buff.close(); 
   }        
   catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

I hope you that's what you needed.

Comment: my text file is like this.

Hit      Run
13        45
16        91
49        55
..        ..
..        ..
like this
array x[13,16,49,...]
array y[45,91,55....]
I want to use these two arrays to plot a graph in XY plane.I will use these points as co-ordinate.
Points are (13,45),(16,91).... so on

Comment: With my implementation you'll read ligne by ligne, so be sure that your file as a pair number per ligne.
After this, use the method ligne.split("the pattern to define the space as a separator"); to generate an array with each number. (I don't remember the pattern to use for the space but you will be able to find it easily in think.
At this point you have an array which contains each number from a ligne, then puts numbers at pair index in your array x and non-pair number in your array y.

Comment: there are multiple columns but I want only two columns.
please provide source code, as I am new to android